# Antivirus for OS X 10.6.8

Tags: software-recommendation, mac-appstore, anti-virus

I have a laptop with OS X 10.6.8, and it needs anti-virus. I went to the App Store, but everything wants 10.7 and later. I need a software recommendation.

Comment: One question per question is best. 10.6.8 app store exists to get you to 10.7 from what I can tell...

Comment: OS X doesn't really need any antivirus, but you are running a very old version in 10.6. I'd just update to 10.11 "El Capitan" if I could and if not just download Avast for Mac.

Comment: I cant update, due to hardware incompatibility.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

One known Antivirus app still running on Mac OS X 10.6.8 is Avast Antivirus 2015 for Mac. [Download link](https://www.avast.com/en-us/index) (almost direct link Avast).

Comment: seriously. ...!

Comment: Be careful using that link, as there are fake "Download Now" buttons that can trick the user into downloading other software.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you NEED an antivirus (In 25 years I have never used one and never had a virus). I do have the free ClamXav which I use to scan external disks before mounting on my Mac.

Comment: I’m happy for you, but your situation does not reflect my experience.

Comment: Agreed. Most Mac users who blindly think they never get malware are unfortunately misguided. Not as bad as Windows, but yes, it DOES happen